# Proper way to use a Knockout template in a Kendo UI Autocomplete control using Knockout-Kendo

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI (latest version) with Knockout-Kendo (0.6.3) and Knockout (2.3.0) and I have a complex situation with an autocomplete where I am attempting to map the input typed into the autocomplete field (a numeric string) to a complex data type on the backend in Javascript.

I don't think all the details are relevant at this point as my problem is understanding how to properly use a named Knockout template with any Kendo UI control other than a grid (because I have that one working).  Essentially I'm trying to style the autocomplete suggestion dropdown based on the the input entered into the autocomplete.

Essentially I've tried this:

```
<input data-bind="kendoAutoComplete: { data: paymentSubCodeCodeList, value: paymentSubCodeCode, template: { name: 'mail_mailPaymentEntry-section_subcode-autocomplete', data: paymentSubCodeCode } }" />
```

but this locks up and throws a javascript knockout error saying object does not support "replace".

I've also tried

```
template: $('#mail_mailPaymentEntry-section_subcode-autocomplete').html()
```

and

```
template: '<div>#: data #</div>'
```

The first one works to create a template but I cannot access any knockout data.  The second one works with data but data is just the value I selected and I need access to associated ViewModel.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if knockout-kendo  supports knockout templates for things other than the grid.

You can write a custom binding which renders a template however

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBinding = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var accessor = valueAccessor();
    //do cool stuff
        ko.renderTemplate("myTemplate", accessor, {}, element, 'replaceNode');
    }
};
```

If a kendo template will due here's an example using them:

http://jsfiddle.net/GQqwY/72/

---

Selected:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
```

this.choices = ko.observableArray([{ Id: 1, Name: 'Andrew' },{ Id: 2, Name: 'John' }, { Id: 3, Name: 'Doe' }]);

```
this.selectedChoice = ko.observable();

this.templ = kendo.template('<div style="color:blue">#= Name #</div>');
```

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

Comment: Well that explains a lot and stops the hair pulling.  I'm still trying to find another way to subvert this but that first one is another good alternative to try.  I'd prefer not to mix-and-match with Kendo templates if at all possible.

Comment: I'm looking at the changeset to add knockout template support to the grids: https://github.com/kendo-labs/knockout-kendo/commit/26e21c4c0666393e6e863302b16e618e86a3d3e1. You might be able to use will auto complete, reading code..

Comment: I couldn't get the knockout templates to work, someone smarter than me probably could. I added an example of using the kendo templates with an autoComplete box if you're interested :-)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind.  Thanks again.  We'll see if anyone else comments on the Knockout template side.

Answer (score 0):

Knockout will accept all options that you give it on the actual widget.

You can include a template option like  :

`<input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { dataTextField: 'name', dataValueField: 'id', 
    data: choices, value: selectedChoice, 
    template: '<span>Name: #: data.name # </span>' }" />`

Here is an example from Niemeyer : http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/jgs9H/

Comment: This has been awhile, but I think my point here was to use Knockout-style templates instead of the Kendo syntax.

Comment: Knockout-style template binding is not available but you can achieve its benefits using Kendo templates as well. The data you are passing to the template should be a knockout property.